# Agrv in Python Needs More Than One Value to Unpack?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv

I have been following the book, "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed A. Shaw. I am currently in exercise 18, and been having this problem since exercise 16. My code is this:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long %r" % len(indata)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continues, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

And the result in the terminal (macOS) is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex17.py", line 4, in <module>
script, from_file, to_file = argv
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I am using macOS High Serria, coding in Atom using Python 2.7 (not built-in).

Thank you!

Comment: How are you running it? Looks like you didn't provide enough arguments.

Comment: It seems that atom is only passing the first argument. You also need to specify the `to_file` argument, something like `python ex18.py path/to/from_file.txt path/to/to_file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
script, from_file, to_file = argv
```

This line means it should be accepting three values from running command:

```
python test.py FileA FileB
```

where your script is `test.py` from_file is `FileA` and to_file is `FileB`

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me! Again, thank you so much!

Comment: You should mark answers as Accepted , as it helps to close question( a common practice on stackoverflow )

Comment: Thank you, iamdeowanshi, for telling me that. I am a new user, thanks!